# Opening and Reading from a "large" gzip compressed file in C

Tags: c, file, io, gzip

I have been trying to open and read a **gzip** compressed file using **gzip-based** file IO functions in C. The compressed file that I have with me is quite large of size 12 GB. The uncompressed file was **~260 GB** and hence I am not prepared to uncompress the file using gunzip and go ahead from there.

I am specifically using the below code to read and write into the buffers available to us-

```
#define windowBits 15
#define ENABLE_ZLIB_GZIP 32

#define CHUNK 0x4000

#define CALL_ZLIB(x) {  \
    int status;     \
    status = x;     \
    if (status < 0) \
    {               \
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: %s returned a bad status of %d.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, #x, status);  \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
    }              \
 }                 \



int main ()
{
    const char * file_name = "test.gz";
    FILE * file;
    z_stream strm = {0};
    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];

    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.next_in = in;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    CALL_ZLIB (inflateInit2 (& strm, windowBits | ENABLE_ZLIB_GZIP));

    /* Open the file. */

    file = fopen (file_name, "rb");

    while (1) {
        int bytes_read;

        bytes_read = fread (in, sizeof (char), sizeof (in), file);

        strm.avail_in = bytes_read;
        do {
            unsigned have;
            strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
            strm.next_out = out;
            CALL_ZLIB (inflate (& strm, Z_NO_FLUSH));
            have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
            fwrite (out, sizeof (unsigned char), have, stdout);
        }
        while (strm.avail_out == 0);
        if (feof (file)) {
            inflateEnd (& strm);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code accurately reads and writes from the zlib file based on a buffer that you specify initially. The buffer size is being fixed to a certain value (in the above case to  **0x4000**).

The problem now is that I cannot increase the size of this buffer beyond a certain value ( **I can use 3276008 as buffer size, but not 32760008** ). To read a 12 GB compressed value, would need me to use a very big buffer. As specified in my edits, this looks like some kind of a `DATA_ERROR` not a `BUFFER`error... so it is not a buffer error after all!

Is there any way how I can be able to record the whole 12 GB compressed file using the `zlib` functions above ?

**EDIT #1**

The error code returned by the function `inflate` is encapsulated by the `CALL_ZLIB` function which I am sorry to have not included. So I get the below error code when I run with the buffer size of 0x4000. I have added the CALL_ZLIB function to the code for your reference also.

**Error msg :**

`parser.c:96: inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH) returned a bad status of -3`. This obviously looks like a **DATA_ERROR.

**EDIT #2**

I have tried adding a **negative value of windowBits** to InflateInit2() but that did not solve any of my problems. The inflate() function initially reads my file correctly -- displaying all of my data the way I want it to..

```
0x55b0 [0x40]: event: 3
.
. ... raw event: size 64 bytes
.  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 18 03 00 00 18 03 00 00  ......@.........
.  0010:  4d 6f 64 65 6d 4d 61 6e 61 67 65 72 00 00 00 00  ModemManager....
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0030:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

0 0 0x55b0 [0x40]: PERF_RECORD_COMM: ModemManager:792/792

0x55f0 [0x40]: event: 7
.
. ... raw event: size 64 bytes
.  0000:  07 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 19 03 00 00 01 00 00 00  ......@.........
.  0010:  19 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0030:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

0 0 0x55f0 [0x40]: PERF_RECORD_FORK(793:793):(1:1)

0x5630 [0x40]: event: 3
.
```

But after some time, the displayed output becomes garbled and I cannot read from it anymore..

```
0x4d68 [0x38]: ...........  001  0..
0 0 00 00 00 0 00 000 00 ze 64s
.  0000:  07 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 19 03 00 00 01 00 00 00  .. 00 0 event: size 64 bytes
.  0000:  03 00 00 00  si sisizsiz4s
.  0000:  07 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 19 0....
.  0030:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ..@.@.  0010:  19 03 00 00 [0x38]: ...........  001  0..
0 0 00 00 00 0 00 000 00 ze 64s
.  0000:  07 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 100 00 00 00 00  ..............0 0 0x4d28 [0x40]: PERF_RECORD_FORK(135:135):(2:62)

0x4d68 [0x38]: ...........  001  0..
0 0 00 00 00 0 00 000 00 00 00 00: PERORD_FORK(135:135):(2:2)
```

This finally terminates with the error message I described in the Edit #1

Comment: `system("/bin/gunzip mybigfile.gz");`? Or `fork() exec()` ...

Comment: gunzip will return me the original file of 260 GB - I was not planning to work with this large file.. that is why I compressed it. I want to easily read and parse this file actually..

Comment: The zlib system takes a small chunk of the file, and decompresses it.  The output from this is filling your out buffer.  Are you trying to "process" the data with 260Mb of IO?  The window size and buffer, do not affect the amount of data which zlib can process

Comment: I already have a .gz file with me. And I am trying to read directly from that file, without uncompressing it as the original file was 260 GB and I managed to reduce it to 12 GB(which is my .gz file). As soon as I increase my buffer, I can see the program reading more data than previous before there is a segfault. But it looks like there is a limit to the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.

The basic problem was that I was not initializing the `strm.next_in` member of z_stream in my code inside the loop. Hence after doing 1 iteration, the buffer got corrupted and I was getting the above errors.

I modified my code to --

```
  strm.next_in = in;
  strm.avail_in = 0;

  CALL_ZLIB(inflateInit2 (&strm, windowBits | ENABLE_ZLIB_GZIP));

  file = fopen(filename, "rb");

  while(1)
  {
    int bytes_read;
    strm.next_in = in;     // added this line

    bytes_read = fread(in, sizeof(char), sizeof(in), file);

    strm.avail_in = bytes_read;

    do
    {
      unsigned have;
      strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
      strm.next_out  = out;
```